# Why can't a variable be passed into the MacVim :colorscheme function?

Tags: vim, macvim

I'd like to set a mapping to loop through a list of colorschemes in MacVim.

Ideally, I'd have an array of color schemes like this:

```
let s:schemes = ['zellner','ron','morning','murphy','peachpuff','torte']
```

And in a function set the colorscheme to an index of this array:

```
colorscheme s:schemes[s:schemeindex]
```

However this above line does not work.  Why?

Instead, I use a workaround which works fine:

```
function SwitchScheme()
    if s:schemeindex == 0
        colorscheme zellner
        s:schemeindex = 1
    elseif s:schemeindex == 1
        colorscheme ron
        s:schemeindex = 2
    ...
    endif
endfunction
```

My question is, is there a cleaner way to do this?  I'd like to pass a variable to the colorscheme setter function but this doesn't seem to be working.

Are these scheme names constants and if so how do you assign them to a variable?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:colorscheme` is just limited, like some others such as `:source`, in that it takes the rest of the line literally, i.e. it can't use a VimL expression as argument. This limitation is generally worked around by using `:execute`, e.g.

```
execute 'colorscheme '.s:mycolors[current]
```

This comes from a [a color scheme switcher posted at the Vim Tips wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip341).